# block_copy when to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

When to copy a block? The document says, blocks are "deleted when execution returns from the scope in which they are defined.This means you can’t return them directly from a function. If blocks could only be used while their defining scope was still on the call stack, they wouldn’t be nearly as useful as they actually are"

So, here is code which I tried, hoping the block will be deleted once execution is completed in viewDidLoad.

**MyReaderController.h**

```
@interface MyReaderController : UIViewController
{
    myBlockVar aBlockVar;
}
-(myBlockVar) getABlock;
@end
```

**MyReaderController.m**

```
@implementation MyReaderController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    aBlockVar=[self getABlock];
    NSLog(@"Block Result = %f",aBlockVar(1));
}
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Block Exists even after the execution completes=%@ %f",aBlockVar,aBlockVar(5));
}

-(myBlockVar) getABlock{
    return ^(int var){return 4.0f;};
}

@end
```

So, does this code require viewDidLoad to be changed to as coded below, if not then when should I use it.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    aBlockVar=Block_copy([self getABlock]);
    NSLog(@"Block Result = %f",aBlockVar(1));
}
```

***PART 2***

Later on I tried with this following code, hoping now it will return aBlockVar as nil obj in 
viewDidDisappear.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Blocker *blocker=[[Blocker alloc] init];
    myBlockVar myVar=[blocker getABlock];
    aBlockVar=myVar;
    NSLog(@"Block Result = %f",aBlockVar(1));
    blocker=nil;
    myVar=nil;
}
```

**Blocker.m**

```
#import "Blocker.h"

@implementation Blocker

-(myBlockVar) getABlock{
    return ^(int var){return 4.0f;};
}
@end
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you using ARC? If so, you don't need to use `Block_copy` or `Block_release`.

If you are, then you are correct with your revised code, as `Block_copy` takes it off the stack and into the heap where it is has an effective retain count of 1. You would also need to call `Block_release` where appropriate, when finally finished with the block, to bring its balance the copy, effectively bringing the retain count back to 0.

Comment: Yes I am using ARC, then why does the object is not getting of the stack, as per what the document says. I think there will be a correction in your second paragraph first line "If you are not using ,then you are......"

Comment: I tried the same code in NON-ARC environment, but still the object exist in viewDidDisappear

Comment: why shouldn't it? you never nil it

Comment: Even under ARC you still need to copy blocks. For example you cannot put a stack block into NSMutableArray of blocks. You'll get ugly crash at some point.

Answer (score 2):

use `@property (nonatomic, copy) (int)(^myBlock)(void);`

let the system do all right memory management for you!

initialize:

```
self.myBlock = ^int(void){
    return 4.0;
};
```

if you want to destroy your block somewhere do `self.myBlock = NULL;`

Comment: Edited the code and made it nil, please let me know what else should I do.

Comment: what do you mean? once you created a property - you can don't care about where and how to copy your blocks, if you want to return it from function, just do self.myBlock = [[[Blocker alloc] init] getABlock]; - at this moment you call auto-generated setter for your block property and it will be copied

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to the existing answers:

Even if you're using ARC, there are certain situations where you still need `Block_copy`.
For example, extracting a block argument from an `NSInvocation` and using it after the function returns.

```
- (void)interceptInvocation:(NSInvocation *)call {
    BlockType block;
    [call getArgument:&block atIndex:2];  // ARC cannot see this happen
    block = (__bridge BlockType)Block_copy((__bridge void *)block);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        block();
    });
}
```

Without the copy, the block will have been deallocated by the time it is run.
It appears a matching `Block_release` is not necessary, as when I added one it crashed due to too many releases.

Comment: This is basically using an incorrect usage to fix another incorrect usage. Your original problem is that `-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]` doesn't do anything about memory management when setting the value into your passed variable. It just copies the bits. However, in ARC, when assigning to a variable of `__strong` ownership (and `BlockType` is an object pointer with `__strong` ownership), you must release the previous value and retain the new value. `-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]` doesn't do that. So it basically it assigns to the variable but is missing a retain.

Comment: `Block_copy()` adds a retain when copying a block that's already on the heap (in this case, the block is already on the heap), and it's supposed to be balanced with a `Block_release()` in the same scope, which adds a release. (Normally, you would use the Objective-C method `-copy` so ARC handles the retain count instead of using `Block_copy()` and `Block_release()`.) Since you use a `Block_copy()` without a `Block_release()`, you are adding an unbalanced (extra) retain. An extra retain happens to cancel out the previous problem of a missing retain.

Comment: Since `[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]` doesn't do memory management, the proper solution would be to give it a non-`__strong` variable type that doesn't expect memory management. You would do something like `__unsafe_unretained BlockType unretainedBlock;
[call getArgument:&unretainedBlock atIndex:2];
BlockType block = (__bridge BlockType)unretainedBlock;`

Comment: @newacct have you tested that actually works for an async dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

**with arc never, without arc:**

---

: when you have a STACK block and want to keep it as a HEAP block (e.g. when you have a block in a function and want it to live after you exited the function!)

You need to block_copy it then.

---

also you need retain/release it as you would a NSString so (using block_copy/block_release)

Comment: true, but after viewDidLoad that object should be nil, I have also tried something else, see the code in Part 2

Comment: @Daiji-Djan, It is object so it can be made nil, I also tried to release the blocker object,[blocker object] in a new project with NON-ARC environment. I tried all the things that I could, made the block var property "aBlockVar" weak, but still after release of that(Blocker) object its not nil. What am I missing, please explain in detail.

Comment: what I said is: you never make it nil. ERGO it will never be nil right now! If you want it to, `aBlockVar = nil;`